# Using str2num to provide a separate file representing time

Tags: matlab

I have a data title of ABCDE_D20110507T11522323 This represents that the data was collected on the May 07 2011 at ta time (after T) at 11:52:23:23. 
Using this script I should be able to extract this information

```
fnames=dir('ABCDE*.mat') 
hour=str2num(fnames(1).data(11:18))
```

`(11:18)` Represents the character number 
What am I doing wrong? should I be specifying the format I want such as (HH,MM,SS) within the script?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `dir` doesn't give me a field called `data`. did you mean `date`... or `name`?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achive a little clearer? Are you trying to extract time info from filename?

Comment: Characters 11:18 don't correspond to any time strings that I can find, either in the date field of dir or in the name you supplied.  And a third : is unusual in a time representation.  What does the final 23 represent?  Hundredths of a second?  Then use a decimal instead.  And describe the output you want.  Matlab datenum?

Comment: HebeleHododo - yes that is what I am trying to do and create a separate file of time. Also my mistake it should be (17:24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the complete date from the filename and then extract hours.

```
fnames = dir('ABCDE*.mat');
for idx = 1:size(fnames, 1)
    str(idx,:) = fnames(idx).name(8:22)
    dateVector(idx,:) = datevec(str(idx,:), 'yyyymmddTHHMMSS') % Convert the string to date vector
    hrs(idx,:) = dateVector(idx,4:6)
end
```

Let's say you have two files in your directory. Your variables will be like:

```
str =

20130228T171052
20130228T143122

dateVector =

        2013           2          28          17          10          52
        2013           2          28          14          31          22


hrs =

    17    10    52
    14    31    22
```

`hrs` will be hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: that is exactly what im looking for. Thank you. However I tried to place this line in str = fnames.name(8:22) and i got the following error. any suggestions? 
Too many outputs requested.
Most likely cause is missing []
around
left hand side that has a comma
separated list expansion.

Comment: @user2013590 The code only worked for one file. I updated it. It should work fine for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Dan, you need to reference field `name` for struct array `fnames` (and not `data` which is invalid).

```
hour = str2double( fname(1).name(17:18) );
```

Comment: My mistake that was a mistype why would using str2double be more beneficial than str2num?